# How can I define my text editor in bashrc?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a variable containing my editor in ~/.bashrc. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be coming through

```
# ~/.bashrc
export EDITOR=sublime
```

in terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
echo $EDITOR
=> nothing
```

How can I set and persist this variable?

### Edit

This is my current .bashrc file:

```
source ~/.profile # Get the paths
source ~/.bashrc  # get aliases

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting


### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export EDITOR=sublime
```

Comment: Normally, you would put environment variables in your .profile or .bash_profile, whichever you use.

Comment: This works for me. Do you `unset` the variable somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would have unset it @pfnuesel. I do have something weird though which is that when I run `source ~/.bashrc` I get the line `[Process completed]` but I can't get back to the terminal prompt. It just sits there blocking the terminal

Comment: Do you have an `exit` statement somewhere in your `.bashrc`? If you can't get back to the terminal prompt, how do you invoke `echo $EDITOR`? Can you show us the contents of your `.bashrc`?

Comment: @pfnuesel - I've just added it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, check your .bash_profile or /etc/bash.bashrc

If your .bashrc isn't sourced, your .bashrc isn't read. All you need to do is source your file or drop your export command in something that is.

Answer (score 0):

The `.bashrc` is only read in when a new shell is created and not when you log in. If you want your `.bashrc` read in during logins, you have to add this line to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.profile`:

```
[ -x $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc
```

Note that `$HOME/.bashrc` must be both readable **and** executable by the user. (i.e., the file permission must be `5..` or `7..`) for it to work. Make sure that your file permissions are set correctly.

Comment: My apologies that I don't know how to comment on this as I'm completely out of my depth with bash. I don't know what constitutes a login (logging into the computer) or creating a new shell (opening a new terminal window?). I realise these are complete newbie questions but somehow I've managed to survive knowing very little about bash!

Comment: No apology is needed. In the old dumb terminal days, you would log into a text based terminal, and that would run your _login_ script (With BASH, that would be `$HOME/.bash_login` or if that doesn't exist `$HOME/.profile`. When you ran a shell script, it would execute your _resource_ file (in BASH, that would be `$HOME/.bashrc`. Things are a bit more complicated now. If I remember, on Solaris, bringing up a new Xterm would run `.bashrc` and not `.bash_profile`. (Okay, this was before BASH, but it ran Kornshell equivalents. On MacOS X, opening a new terminal window runs `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Comment: As my previous comment explained: It's more complicated today. A shell script starts a new shell (or typing in `bash` as a command) and that will run `.bashrc`. Sometimes when you open a new terminal window, it is considered a new _shell_ and `$HOME/.bashrc` will execute. Sometimes, it is considered a new login, and `$HOME/.bash_profile` is executed. My advice is to put an echo statement in `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` and see which echo statement you see when you open a new window.

Comment: BTW the only reason I haven't accepted your answer yet is that I can't yet confirm that it's the solution that works. I will as soon as I do though